# Devops Copy Files Task is not finding the artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-server-2019

I am trying to setup a release pipeline with the agent installed on a Linux Server to deploy a node.js app.

I am trying to copy files from Agent’s Default Working Directory to my destination directory and using Copy File task. But Copy Files Task logs show **“found 0 files”**

Logs show that the **“Download Artifacts”** task is completed successfully and artifacts are downloaded properly in ***“/root/azagent/_work/r1/a/_NodeAPIs/drop”*** and I can see the zip file in the server.

Here are the details for Copy Files Task. (for some reason i am unable to upload and attach image to the question)

https://www.akashif.co.uk/CopyFileTask.png

> SourceFolder:$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_NodeAPIs/drop/APIs.zip
>
> Contents: **
>
> Target Folder: /node/testing/apis/

I have tried using different Content filters such as  "**.zip* , ** and *.zip"
with all my efforts I always receive **“found 0 files”** in Copy Files Task logs

Please advise.

Comment: See documentation provided by Microsoft. Basically you need publish task to paste item to destination. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your task definition, the cause of the issue is that you only need to define the folder path where the zip file locates to **SourceFolder** field instead of the detailed zip file path.

Refer to the following sample:

[image]

> SourceFolder:$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_NodeAPIs/drop
>
> Contents: APIs.zip
>
> Target Folder: /node/testing/apis/